# Channel bonding on Lumia 1020

Tags: wifi, nokia-lumia-1020

How do I setup channel bonding for my Lumia 1020 with Linksys E1000 router?

For the router WiFi setting, I already set its channel width to Auto (20/40hz), but still getting 20Mbps instead of 50Mbps on desktop with Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding#Wi-Fi) that is not channel bonding

> On IEEE 802.11n, a mode with a channel width of 40 MHz is specified.
>   This is not channel bonding, but a single channel with double the
>   older 20 MHz channel width, thus using two adjacent 20 MHz bands.

Since it uses two adjacent channels you should try changing your Wi-Fi channel since there may be interference. I would also recommend changing it from 'Auto' to '40Mhz' to test if you can in fact get higher speeds than 20Mbps.

Comment: The setting for channel width on my router only have "20 MHz" or "Auto (20/40)MHz", does that mean I'm out of luck getting 50 MHz with my router? I tried to switch channel numbers but that doesn't help much.